# How to reset rpc settings in ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, grpc, rpc

I'm coding a python project in PyCharm with a remote Ubuntu server. However, the rpc in the server breaks down for now, and I cannot debug my python project in pycharm. The report error is like

```
Error running 'main': While creating remote tunnel for SshjSshConnection(root@11.158.195.246)@b28cb9d: localhost:6430
```

Also, I cannot run the grpc-related project in the server, the report error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    executor_info = self.serialize_response(self.report_executor_info_handler())
  File "/xxxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/xxxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1656483862.995493949","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3186,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1656483862.995493294","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc","file_line":146,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>
```

It seems like the rpc of the server breaks down, and reboot the server doesn't work. So, is there any way to deal with the above error, or reset the rpc?

Comment: Please include more information. Include (a minimally reproducible example of) the client and server code that you're using, how you're running the client and server and an explanation of the network between the two.

Comment: If they're distinct hosts, can you e.g. ping the server from the client machine?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) (or similar) to connect to the server from the client? What was the result?

Comment: Are you able to successfully run one of the [quickstart examples](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/)?